# Determining the formula of sodium carbonate hydrate using acid-base titration

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, titration

I found this question online at mathsmadeeasy.com:

> Sodium carbonate exists in hydrated form, $\ce{Na2CO3 · x H2O},$ in the solid state. $\pu{3.5 g}$ of a sodium carbonate sample was dissolved in water and the volume made up to $\pu{250 cm3}.$ $\pu{25.0 cm3}$ of this solution was titrated against $\pu{0.1 mol dm-3}$ $\ce{HCl}$ and $\pu{24.5 cm3}$ of the acid were required. Calculate the value of $x$ given the equation:
>
> $$\ce{Na2CO3 + 2 HCl -> 2 NaCl + CO2 + H2O}.$$

I have spent around 20 minutes trying to figure out the final steps to this question. I was able to workout the amount of sodium carbonate in $\pu{250 cm3}$ as $\pu{1.225E-2 mol},$ but I don't know how to use this to finish off the question, please help.

Comment: If you do not say what you have tried, we cannot say what you did wrong.

Comment: The problem is not too challenging. Think of mass balance. Given the fact that you have determined the moles of sodium carbonate. Determine the grams of sodium carbonate. It should be less than 3.5 g. Where is the rest of the mass coming from? I guess it is water. Add these steps in the question, and hopefully we will find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

@ FP. You have done most of the job. You are nearly at the end. You have found that the amount of $\ce{Na2CO3}$ is $ n = 0.01225$ mol. The only thing you still have to calculate is the molar mass of the initial compound : $M = m/n = 3.5$ g/$0.01225$ mol = $286$ g/mol.
As anhydrous $\ce{Na2CO3}$ has a molar mass of $106$ g/mol, the difference $286$ g/mol - $106$ g/mol = $180$ g/mol is $x$ times the molar mass of $\ce{H2O}$, which is $18$ g/mol. So $x$ = $180/18 = 10$, and the formula of your initial compound is $\ce{Na2CO3·10H2O}$

Answer (score 1):

This is a different way to calculate $x$. Suppose amount of $\ce{Na2CO3}$ in $\pu{3.5 g}$ of sample is $n$ $\pu{mol}$. Thus, the amount of water in the same sample is $n$ $\pu{mol}$. Since molar masses of $\ce{Na2CO3}$ and $\ce{H2O}$ are $105.99$ and $\pu{18.02 g mol-1}$, respectively,

$$105.99n + 18.02nx = 3.5 \tag1$$

Since most of the measurements are in two significant figures, it is okay to round these numbers. Thus, after simplification:
$$18.0x = \frac{3.5}{n} -106 \tag2$$

By your calculations, you found $n = 1.225 \times 10^{-2}$. Applied this values in the equation $(2)$:

$$18.0x = \frac{3.5}{1.225 \times 10^{-2}} -106 \approx 180 \ \Rightarrow \ \therefore \ x = \frac{180}{18} = 10$$

Thus, your original hydrate is $\ce{Na2CO3.10H2O}$.